# Calculate current speed / stop running when player hit walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, box2d

**Background:**

I have a 2D platformer that lets the player run (you guessed it) either left or right. I have many different animations set up to simulate events like running, walking and jumping. They are all dependent on the Player's Rigidbody2D Velocity. If it's 0 then simply stand still, If it's larger, then run and so on. My question is, whenever the player runs into a wall the velocity is still above zero (even if the character is not moving)

**So how can I calculate the true velocity or stop the player from running when hitting objects?**

Comment: Have you tried `player.Velocity = Vector2(0,0)` ?

Comment: @ja72 I know that that sets the players velocity to zero, but when should that happen? That's why I need the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method would be check his position at the beginning and end of each frame. If the position has not moved then he is not moving.

Comment: I thought about that too. Would you consider it a good way or just a way?

Comment: Just a way, you could also do a Raycast to check if something is in front of you. If there is stop moving.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using GetLinearVelocity to check the velocity of the player body. I would also assume you are using SetLinearVelocity to make the player move (this is the only way you would end up with a non-zero value returned from GetLinearVelocity while the body is not actually moving).

If this is the case, then you are simply setting a value and reading it back again. The simple solution is, don't do that :)

You can use ApplyForce or ApplyLinearImpulse to move the player body, then GetLinearVelocity will return the true velocity instead of just giving you the same value you set yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a collision event with a wall using [OnCollisionEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html). When your object hits anything, this function will be called. If you tag anything that you want the player to stop at (e.g., Wall), you can detect specific collisions and behave accordingly:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if(collision.gameObject.tag="Wall") {
        //your player has just hit the wall. congratulations!
        //don't set velocity to zero here, because then he'll just stop in midair or something!
    }
}
```

One thing I've noticed in the past is that without a strong friction force affecting your player, their velocity will stay at miniscule but still non-zero values for a while. To compensate, you can determine a "stopped" threshold. For example, if `rigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude` falls below `0.0001`, your object has most likely "stopped" in the sense that he won't move very much anymore. There is very little difference between a velocity of `0` and `0.00000000763168381`. So instead of checking for a velocity of zero, check for a velocity that is really really really small.